# Choosing which private ip address to communicate with on a server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, soap

I am writing .NET application for a server that has multiple private ip addresses assigned to it.

There will two different SOAP Service's that I need to communicate with, but they require me to communicate over a different IP address for each.

For example,

Application ----> 10.0.0.20 -----> SOAP Service1

Same Application ----> 10.0.0.21 -----> SOAP Service2

Unfortunately I do not have control over this.

**So basically, I would like to make it appear as if it is coming from two different ip addresses.**

I have generated the code from the WSDL, is there any chance you can tell me if this is possible via Channel Factory or another way?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you saying you want your requests to the two different SOAP services to appear as though they are coming from two separate IP addresses?

Comment: That is correct.  I will update the question to make it clearer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is spoof your IP address for your two instances of the application. You cannot do this with simple C# code. You may be able to use a proxy server of some sort to accomplish this but, you can't accomplish it by C# alone.

Alternatively, you could run your application on two separate servers; one with .20 and the other with .21 as it's IP address.